# API call with axios fails if special characters are present in the API output

Tags: node.js, axios, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently creating an Alexa Skill with node.js and have axios loaded with version 0.21.1.
If the queried API returns normal characters everything works without problems. However, if there is a &, the call fails. Why does it do that?

Here is my code:

```
const name = 'example';
    
const apiUrl= function() {
   return `https://example.com/${name}`
}
    
const APIRequest = async (url) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('cannot fetch quotes', error);
    }
};

const APIHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'APIIntent'
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        try {
            const [Data] = await Promise.all([
                (APIRequest(apiUrl()))
            ]);
            const speechText = `Data 1: ${Data.1}, Data 2: ${Data.2}`;
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak(speechText)
              .getResponse();
        } catch (error) {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak('Unfortunately I do not know at the moment')
              .getResponse();
        }
    },
};
```

Here is the API output

Works:

```
{
    "1": "this is a text",
    "2": "this is a text"
}
```

Does not work:

```
{
    "1": "this is a text & more information",
    "2": "this is a text"
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Can you provide the API output and the error details as well?

Comment: I am new to using Alexa. I can't tell which error it is. I don't know where to find the error log. 
I looked online but I can't find CloudWatch logs.

Comment: @deechris27, i have provided the API output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding for alexa skill using nodejs, my presumption was you might be doing so with AWS lambda, in this case I suggest using [lambda local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) or [serverless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless)

I understand it is difficult to debug if you're not using above options.

I have two suggestions for your issue,

**First one:** Axios interceptors. It is very likely to work though I personally didn't get a chance to use it in Alexa skill development.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    let data = response.headers["content-type"];
    if (data.includes("charset=ISO-8859-1")) {
        responsee.data = data.decode(response.data, 'ISO-8859-1');
    }
    return response;
});
```

Ref:- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/332

**Second Approach:**  Encode response and decode response.data to the desired format

use [iso-8859-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-8859-2)

```
const response = await axios.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.test.com',
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  responseEncoding: 'binary'
});
```

let result = iso88592.decode(response.data.toString('binary'));

Comment: Thank you very much. In the meantime I have found the error log and found out that it was due to the speak output (SSML). This does not support certain characters.
I change the unsupported characters to HTML format in the future and now it works.